# Red5: Get rtmp stream in java

Tags: java, red5, rtmp

How to get the current rtmp stream in java on server side?I have seen many pages in StackOverflow, but I got nothing helpful.I think this is a common question.I will be thankful if any one can help me.

Comment: In what form do you want the rtmp stream? How do you want to use it?

Comment: best like this form: java.io.InputStream getCurrentRtmpStream(); I can use the stream to do more processing then.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to add a Consumer or PipeListener is available on the server side. Using these means you can do whatever you like with the data coming in from the stream. This old nabble post also has more details on stream event capture: http://old.nabble.com/how-can-i-capture-stream-event-in-a-plugin--td28349277.html

Comment: Thanks for your advise.I've got a lot help from it.